1D Ring Ising model with kinetic rates
I have a system of $N$ spins on a ring which undergo linear kinetics.
the spins can assume values of 0 and 1 (super important).
The dynamics of each spin correspond to
$\frac{dn_i}{dt}=k_{on}(1-n_i)-k_{off}n_i$
therefore at steady state we have
$n_i=\frac{k_{on}}{k_{on}+k_{off}}$
I wish to add in addition ising interactions between the spins on the ring
how would the new kinetic model look like?
something of this form?
$\frac{dn_i}{dt}=(k_{on}+W_{0\rightarrow 1})(1-n_i)-(k_{off}+W_{1\rightarrow 0})n_i$
what would be the steady state of $n$ (analytical formulation)
